# Sound indicator issues after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, indicator, indicator-sound

I upgraded t 14.04 yesterday and now the sound indicator disappears every time I run Pithos. Also the media keys don't work. I tried showkey, and the system reads the keys fine, but nothing happens. Is this a known bug or is something else wrong with my system?

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one with this issue. Since Pithos' website links to GitHub for bug tracking I suspect that is the appropriate place to troubleshoot the problem.

https://github.com/pithos/pithos/issues/90

FYI you can restart the panel by running `killall unity-panel-service` in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Until they fix the bug i found a nifty workaround, works flawlessly for me.. just restart **indicator-sound-service**

Or create a Pithos start-up icon/app by saving the following code into a [whatever].sh (bash script file):

> > #!/bin/bash
>
> pithos & sleep 3 && /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
>
> > > ##if you arent running 64-bit just change the path to the sound-service as appropriate

--it starts pithos, sleeps for 3 seconds to allow program to bootup, then restarts the sound service. Cheers! Dont forget to modify the permissions of the file to allow it to execute:

sudo chmod 755 [whatever].sh

--then just create youself a nifty icon-launcher and you are good to go!